# Why filter by Contact name not working?

Tags: soql, permissions

I have simple query on contact

```
select id, name from Contact where name ='John E Doe'
```

Even if the Contact with name 'John E Doe' present in the system, the soql is returning 0 results.

Why this strange behavior, please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name field only allows you to query whatever it returns from the API; in my org it only supports specifically the First Name and Last Name, so I can query for:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Brian Fear'
```

But I can't search on extra fields, such as:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Mr. Brian Fear'
```

If you need to be able to filter by middle names, for example, you'll probably need to be more specific, like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'John Doe' AND MiddleName = 'E'
```

Comment: apparently there is a platform bug related to this.... see my answer below if you are running into unexplainable issues even after trying to be selective on name parts as outlined here

Answer (score 2):

This actually appears to be a platform bug.  I just ran into it and it almost drove me to insanity:

**REPRO**

```
Contact c = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0031J00001Hewjy'];
System.debug(c);
Contact c2 = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = :c.FirstName AND LastName = :c.LastName];
System.debug(c2);
```

**RESULT:**

```
01:52:32.1 (2478415)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[1]|Aggregations:0|SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0031J00001Hewjy'
01:52:32.1 (6281865)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[1]|Rows:1
01:52:32.1 (6663245)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Contact:{FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Id=0031J00001HewjyQAB, RecordTypeId=0121J000000uGo4QAE}
01:52:32.1 (7018840)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[3]|Aggregations:0|SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE (FirstName = :tmpVar1 AND LastName = :tmpVar2)
01:52:32.1 (23897860)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[3]|Rows:0
01:52:32.1 (24425335)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1
```

Only seems to impact records with middle names.  While this statement fails in the Full Copy it works in Production so who knows what is causing this.

My guess would be a bad index is created during sandbox copy... Simplify updating the first and last name fixed the issue for this specific record.

Comment: great sleuthing.  I'm experiencing the same issue in our org that has MiddleName/Suffix turned on.  Any chance you've logged a ticket or found a Known Issue for this bug?

Comment: @BrentBow I don't think so... I've submitted enough platform bugs to learn that it's typically not worth your time

Comment: Agreed, @NSjonas. But I felt compelled to follow thru on this bug--you know, "on principle."  After being escalated to Tier 2 and then the Reporting team, we got this response: "Our product development team is reviewing the known issue. Please rest assure that the issue will be fixed very soon."  They closed the Case with Status "Closed - Bug Fix Submitted."

Hopefully this is promising and the "very soon" bit can be believed.  They said the issue would be addressed under this in-review Known Issue that you can upvote: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWq8QAG

Answer (score 0):

This query perfectly works, either use Dev console Query Editor or Execute Anonymous. You would be doing something strange. Look at following working Screenshots (query is exactly same as your question) below:

> First Name = 'John' 
>   Last Name = 'E Doe'

**Detail Page:**
[image]

**Query Editor Result:**

[image]

**Execute Anonymous Result:**

[image]

You will have to dig yourself more into the approach which can cause this issue. Issue can be little as a typo mistake or can be a field permission or how API join fields issue (can be too many reasons). Salesforce queried it correct.

But note that `MiddleName` can be ignored. Query may consider 'First Name' + 'Last Name'. Orgs even don't show `middle name field. It needs to be enabled. See below:
[image]

There is no such strange behavior (bug or exception) in query Contact.

Comment: maybe not in your org, but that doesn't mean that one doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

if you edit a name in Conatct record it will show a popup as below, so this proves Salesforce does not store the name in a Single field.

[image]

You can't do any caculation in SOQl as you do in SQL. So you can't put this expression FirstName + ' ' + LastName in a SOQL query string.

Source -https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xWKIAY

As per the [Salesforce documentation for Contact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) object The Name field is actually made up of 3 different fields First Name, Last Name and Salutation.

Field

Name

Type : string

Properties : Filter, Group, Sort

Description : 
Concatenation of FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix. Maximum size is 121 characters.

That's why you were not able to get the result with your Query.